# Code for Proportional Variability

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, equation

How to code the equation for proportional variability (equation 1 of this [paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0084074&type=printable))?

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd

l = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6]) # any list of numbers
n = len(l)
if n > 1:
    C = (n*(n-1))/2

    D = []
    for i in l.index:
        for j in l.index:
            if i != j:
                zi_zj = [l[i],l[j]]
                D.append(1-((min(zi_zj))/(max(zi_zj))))

    PV = (1/C)*(np.sum(D))
else:
    PV = 0
```

If I put a list with all numbers the same, I get `PV = 0`, as expected, however, if I put a list with an arithmetic sequence e.g. `[0,2,4,6,8]`, `PV = 1.4`, and according to the paper, `PV` should be between `0` and `1`, and an arithmetic sequence should have a `PV = 0.5` independent of sample size `n`.

Another option I tried was:

```
l = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6]) # any list of numbers
n = len(l)
if n > 1:
    C = (n*(n-1))/2

    i_s = set()
    j_s = set()
    D = []
    for i in l.index:
        for j in l.index:
            if i != j:
                if i not in i_s:
                    if j not in j_s:
                        zi_zj = [l[i],l[j]]
                        D.append(1-((min(zi_zj))/(max(zi_zj))))
                        i_s.add(i)
                        j_s.add(j)

    PV = (1/C)*(np.sum(D))
else:
    PV = 0
```

But didn't work either.

Also, I didn't find a function in Python that calculates the Proportional Variability of a sequence of numbers.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong in the code or let me know if there is an in-built function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the calculations I have done, the value `0.5` only holds for large `n`; please check whether I made a mistake (did not check the paper in detail).

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

l = pd.Series(list(range(3)))

n = len(l)
C = n * (n - 1) / 2.

# get all pairs in l
pairs = list(combinations(l, 2))
```

So pairs then looks as follows:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```

We can now store that in a dataframe as you already work with pandas which makes subsequent calculations quite easy:

```
# store pairs in dataframe
df_pairs = pd.DataFrame(pairs).rename(columns={0: 'zi', 1: 'zj'})

# get max / min for each pair
max_val = df_pairs.max(axis=1)
min_val = df_pairs.min(axis=1)
df_pairs['max_z'] = max_val
df_pairs['min_z'] = min_val

# absolute difference between z
df_pairs['diff_z_abs'] = (df_pairs['zi'] - df_pairs['zj']).abs()

df_pairs['ratio_diff_max'] = df_pairs['diff_z_abs'] / df_pairs['max_z']
df_pairs['one_minus_ratio'] = 1. - df_pairs['min_z'] / df_pairs['max_z']
```

By now the dataframe looks like this:

```
   zi  zj  max_z  min_z  diff_z_abs  ratio_diff_max  one_minus_ratio
0   0   1      1      0           1             1.0              1.0
1   0   2      2      0           2             1.0              1.0
2   1   2      2      1           1             0.5              0.5
```

The value `PV` is then simply:

```
PV = df_pairs['ratio_diff_max'].sum() / C
```

For this example it is `0.83333333`, so much higher than `0.5`. However, if we now change

```
l = pd.Series(list(range(3)))
```

to larger values, `PV` then approaches `0.5`. For example, for

```
l = pd.Series(list(range(5000)))
```

I obtain

```
0.500199
```

So it probably only holds for `n` towards infinity.